# Flutter Plugin / iOS / CallKit Provider doesn't receive CXStartCallAction event

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-packages

We're creating a TwilioProgrammableVoice plugin for Flutter : https://github.com/izio38/twilio_programmable_voice/tree/ios-platform.

Basically what example application should do when pressing a button :

1. Call the plugin method `makeCall`
2. Plugin method should invoke platform specific method named `makeCall`
3. It should then create a `CXStartCallAction` on the CXController
4. On completion, it should update the call to the `CXProivder`
5. The `perform` method should be invoked because we delegated to `self`, with a StartCallAction.

For some reason that I cannot identify by myself, the 5. point isn't done.

Here is the iOS `makeCall` content (reduced on purpose):

```swift
// In TwilioProgrammableVoice.swift
public class TwilioProgrammableVoice: NSObject {
    func makeCall(to: String) {
        print("makeCall to", to)
        if self.twilioVoiceDelegate!.call != nil && self.twilioVoiceDelegate!.call?.state == .connected {
            self.twilioVoiceDelegate!.userInitiatedDisconnect = true
            self.callKitDelegate.performEndCallAction(uuid: self.twilioVoiceDelegate!.call!.uuid!)
        } else {
            // Probably not the right place for such an assignment
            TwilioVoice.audioDevice = audioDevice;
            let uuid = UUID()
            print("UUID : ", uuid)
            self.callKitDelegate.performStartCallAction(uuid: uuid, handle: to)
        }
    }
}

// In CallKitDelegate.swift
class CallKitDelegate: NSObject, CXProviderDelegate {
    var callKitProvider: CXProvider
    let callKitCallController = CXCallController()

    override init () {
        let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: SwiftTwilioProgrammableVoicePlugin.appName)
        callKitProvider = CXProvider(configuration: configuration)

        super.init();

        // We do delegate so we are notified when events occurs on CXProvider
        callKitProvider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    // This isn't always triggered
    public func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {
        print("provider called CXStartCallAction")
        provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, startedConnectingAt: Date())

        TwilioProgrammableVoice.sharedInstance.performVoiceCall(uuid: action.callUUID, client: "") { (success) in
            print("in performVoiceCall cb")
                if success {
                    print("success case")
                        provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, connectedAt: Date())
                } else {
                    print("not success case")
                }
        }

        action.fulfill()
    }
}
```

The strange part is that it works sometimes, and sometimes not. When it does work, we have tons of logs coming from both Twilio and CX.

When it's not working, we have logs that come from CX (I think, I cannot say for sure), since our application doesn't log anything with emoji. It does says : `:thumbup: VoIP CXStartCallAction` and `:microphone: didActivate audioSession`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using another plugin that init a `CXProvider`. And it was init after mine. So it got like 'replaced'.